# predict_proba does not output probability

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I am following

https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html

specificly: https://gist.github.com/ritazh/a7c88875053c1106e407300fc4f1d8d6

When I try and get the actual P values for the prediction using model.predict_proba(x) I get [[1.]] or [[0.]], not a decimal value like 0.69.
Is this because I am using a sigmod activation with only two classes or something wrong with my setup?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try normalization of your input (e.g. by using `MinMaxScaler` etc.) because as your data is not scaled - this might cause a problem.

Comment: Thanks, I will try using this later, probably with model.add(BatchNormalization()) and see if it works

Answer (score 1):

Using `model.predict_proba(x)` on a `Sequential` model should indeed produce decimal values. In my case, most of the values are equal to either `0.` or `1.` but some of them (very few) actually take intermediate values. Check [this example of predictions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOV31.png) that were generated by my model (about 9000 input samples were evaluated).

I reckon this could be due to the sigmoid I use for the output layer. It is possible that the results get squished towards 1 or 0 due to the properties of the sigmoid activation function.

So make sure to check a bunch of different inputs and visualize your outputs. Here is an [example](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-make-classification-and-regression-predictions-for-deep-learning-models-in-keras/) that may be useful.

Also, make sure to **normalize** your inputs, this is typically a reason for which the sigmoid might squish the output!